# Marionette js routing - What am I doing wrong here? I'm getting error that route actions are undefined?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

Just want to get some basic routing up and going.  Having seen a number of examples I thought the code below should work, but when I run I get the error "Unable to get property 'doChat' of undefined or null reference".  Do I have the initialization sequence wrong?

```
    require(["marionette", "jquery.bootstrap", "jqueryui"], function (Marionette) {
        window.App = new Marionette.Application();

        App.start();

        App.addRegions({
        //add some regions here
        });

        //Set up routing       
        var AppRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
            appRoutes: {
                "": "doDefault",
                "chat": "doChat"
            },

            doDefault: function () {
                alert("doing default...")
            },
            doChat: function () {
                alert("doing chat...")
            }
        });

        var router = new AppRouter();

        //History
        if (Backbone.history) {
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppRouter allows two types of routes, standard backbone routes as defined in the `routes` property and routes which call functions in another object defined in the `appRoutes` property.

So to get you above code working, you can do one of two things. The quickest is simply to change the `appRoutes` property to `routes` which will do normal backbone routing. The second option is to create another object and pass that to the `AppRouter` as the controller during instantiation:

```
var myController = {
    doDefault: function () {
        alert("doing default...")
    },
    doChat: function () {
        alert("doing chat...")
    }
}

var router = new AppRouter({
    controller: myController
});
```

This is detailed in the AppRouter [documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.approuter.md).

Comment: Yep.  I see.  Option #2, the controller option is working and seems best to me.  Thanks for that.  I'm thinking those objects, router and controller, should be in separate files.  I see some examples of it and am gonna give it a try.  I have some other questions on whether I should even be using routing to accomplish what I'm after but they belong in a separate post.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I agree they should be in separate files. My apps tend to operate on a one object per file basis. Keeps things clean.